# FindPeaks not returning peaks and its locations with my data?

Tags: matlab, plot, analysis

I am using findPeaks as follows but it return null arrays of peaks and location. Do anyone know what could be the issue, whether its my data issue?

```
[PKS,LOCS]=findpeaks(X);
```

My X has following values:

0.0250000000000000  0.0500000000000000  0.0500000000000000  0.0500000000000000  0.0750000000000000  0.100000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.125000000000000   0.150000000000000   0.175000000000000   0.175000000000000   0.200000000000000   0.225000000000000   0.225000000000000   0.225000000000000   0.225000000000000   0.225000000000000   0.225000000000000   0.225000000000000   0.250000000000000   0.275000000000000   0.275000000000000   0.275000000000000   0.300000000000000   0.325000000000000   0.350000000000000   0.375000000000000   0.400000000000000   0.400000000000000   0.400000000000000   0.425000000000000   0.425000000000000   0.425000000000000   0.425000000000000   0.450000000000000   0.475000000000000   0.500000000000000   0.525000000000000   0.550000000000000   0.550000000000000   0.550000000000000   0.575000000000000   0.600000000000000   0.625000000000000   0.650000000000000   0.675000000000000   0.675000000000000   0.675000000000000   0.700000000000000   0.775000000000000   0.800000000000000   0.825000000000000   0.825000000000000   0.825000000000000   0.850000000000000   0.875000000000000   0.900000000000001   0.925000000000001   0.925000000000001   0.925000000000001   0.925000000000001   0.950000000000001   0.975000000000001   0.975000000000001   1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000    1.00000000000000

Answer (score 0):

There is no peak present in your data, you have just a rising function which ends at a flat top.

You may detect what you want to detect using a max() function.
You may want to provide a full blown code and data example for more detailed discussion.

Comment: The question was about Matlab, not Python

Comment: Sorry, correct, but also in matlab there is no peak in that data ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no peak, use max instead

```
[val, idx] = max(X)
```

Or if you want to find the upper value of rising edges, perhaps this may work:

```
idx =(find(X(1:end-2)<X(2:end-1) & X(2:end-1) >= X(3:end))) + 1
```

Comment: I need to get all up steps. like the value increase after some time. so i need to get all those points. Like in above data the first value is 0.025 then it changes to 0.05 then it goes to 0.075. So i need to mark all these points in my plot.